# Inkscape set transform-origin in the preferences

Tags: transform, preferences, inkscape

I would like the transofrmations of Inkscape (applied to the SVG elements it manages) to be calculated from the center of the element bounding box and not from the upper-left corner (as it does by default).
Is there the possibility to do that?
Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to Inkscape so maybe there are better ways to do this, but here is a simple workaround:

In the 'Tool Controls Bar' each object has values for X, Y, W, and H.
Interestingly, these boxes will evaluate expressions, so if you want to center a text box at the point (U, V), you can enter `U - W/2` for the X value and `V - H/2` for the Y value.

After you have your object centered on the position you choose, then you can apply any transformations you wish since transformations are applied relative to the object's current position.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Tnx lucidMonkey but I indended to evaluate the position of an object it programmatically via C# by reading the transform matrix in the SVG. So I wanted to know if there's a simple method to change the settings in InkScape to let it save transforamtion matrix forom the center of an object instead thet from it's uppper-left corner.

Answer (score 0):

to the generated SVG (remember to save final file as optimized SVG for performance purposes but keep the original for further updates), you can add a CSS rule that will establish that any SVG children (text, path, ellipse, etc.) will transform based on its own center:

```
 svg>* {
    transform-origin: unset;
}
```